# Convert JSON string to Array in AngluarJs Or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Convert JSON string to Array in AngularJS

Example JSON String:

```
"{"Madinaguda":1,"Basheer Bagh":1}"
```

Requirement output like the below:

```
var reuslt= [{ LocationsName : Madinaguda ,LocationCount:1 },
            { LocationsName : Basheer Bagh , LocationCount :1}];
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? (looping over the keys?)

Comment: Reading your question makes me feel I'm writing an exam!!

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty simple solution:

```
var jsonStr = '{"Madinaguda":1,"Basheer Bagh":1}',
    json = JSON.parse(jsonStr),
    result = [];

for (var key in json) {
    if(json.hasOwnProperty(key) ) {
        result.push({
            LocationsName: key,
            LocationCount: json[key]
        });
    }
}

// result is what you want
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
function parseIt(jsonString) {
    "use strict";        
    var result = [], parsedObject, key;

    parsedObject= JSON.parse(jsonString);
    for(key in parsedObject) {
        if(parsedObject.hasOwnProperty(key) ) {
            result.push({LocationsName : key, LocationCount : parsedObject[key]});
        }
     }
     return result;     
}
```

Heres a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2jetqxkq/)